# File should save to client desktop, instead it is saving to server desktop

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, path, environment-variables

I have an application that allows the user to upload and download a file to the server.  When I click download, the process works, however, it is saving it to the wrong place.  When the user clicks download, I want it to save the file to the users desktop, however, when they click download, it is saving the file to the server in a desktop folder that must have gotten created by the application in the applications name.

To sum it up: I want to save to the client's desktop.  Instead it saved to the server at:

> C:\Users\RHAField\Desktop

(**RHAField is the Application Name**)

This is my code to download the file.

Here I am declaring the locations then calling the StartDownload method.  The VisitFile is retrieved from the database based on the ID of the download button and then combined with the paths.

```
string DownloadLocation = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "visits\\download\\");
string SaveLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory); 
VisitFile = (string)SQLCommand.ExecuteScalar();
StartDownload(Path.Combine(DownloadLocation, VisitFile), Path.Combine(SaveLocation, VisitFile));
```

The StartDownload() Method:

```
private void StartDownload(string DownloadSource, string SaveLocation)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(DownloadSource), SaveLocation);
            });
            thread.Name = "aFieldDownload";
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            DownloadPercent = 999;
        }
    }
```

How do I get it to save to the Clients desktop instead of the server correctly?  Is something wrong with my SaveLocation Path?  Is there a better way to get the path other than SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory?

Comment: A web application can't write to the client's file system.  (Imagine a world where any website you visit could access your file system.)  The web application would need to *return* the file to the client in response to a request.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about doing that?  They already need to push a download button, is there a different way should handle it?

Comment: When they "push the download button", presumably they are making a request to the web application, right?  The response to that request should then be the file they want to download.  Look up how to return a file in ASP.NET (using whatever framework(s) you might be using).  There are *tons* of examples online.  The code in the question doesn't even really show how the request is being received in the first place.

Comment: I am spawning a worker thread to do the download so that I can track and show the progress to the user on a progress bar. Is it possible to continue to do that if I return the File?

Comment: Yes, but it would change the UX slightly.  The current button would initiate the process of fetching the file from the remote resource to the server.  Once that tracked progress is complete, the file is now "ready for download" and another button would be shown to the user to download it.  In between these two actions, you can save the file to a temporary location on the server.  When the second button is pressed, simply return that file to the client.

Comment: The file is already located on the server.  Would I just have a download button that returns the file to the user and it would just use the browser downloader and progress? Is my progress bar basically useless?

Comment: If the file originates on the server then, ya, it sounds like you've added an entirely unnecessary step.